# Use Addon domain within login name for FTP account in cPanel

Tags: domains, cpanel, ftp, parking

Let's say I have a cPanel (version 11.30.6 (build 3), cPanel Pro 1.0 (RC1)) shared hosting account for `myDomain.com`.

I also have several [other "Addon" domain names](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/AddonDomains) on this account, each with their own document root.

Under the cPanel FTP Accounts page, it only allows me to do this...

**Server:**  `ftp.myDomain.com`
**Login:**  `name@myDomain.com`

However, I want to setup an FTP location at one of my "Addon" domains so that it looks like this...

**Server:**  `ftp.myAddonDomain.net`
**Login:**  `name@myAddonDomain.net`

I'm not seeing if it's even possible, but hoping it is, and somebody here would be able to explain how.

In other words, cPanel allows me to create an email account at literally **any** of my Addon domains or sub-domains.  I'm wondering if I can create FTP accounts in the same fashion... but it's looks like I cannot.

Comment: Would you mind if the address was ftp.myAddonDomain.myDomain.com? I can tell you how to do that.

Comment: Looks like @toomanyairmiles has done it now!

Comment: @paulmorriss sorry about that.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles Not a problem.

Comment: @paulmorriss, `ftp.myAddonDomain.myDomain.com` does not really solve anything for me.  I'm trying to use one domain name in place of the other.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed this with Tech Support at my hosting provider.

It's not possible to have unique FTP accounts without using the main domain name within the server & login names.

Answer (score 2):

This [FAQ relates to BlueHost](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/7) but it should also apply to other cPanel .nstallations.

It looks to me, and this matches my memory, that the FTP is created along with the addon domain.

Quoting from [siteground](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/addon_domains.htm):

- Step 1: To access the Addon Domains tool, click on the corresponding
  icon located on the main screen of your cPanel interface.
- Step 2: Enter the name of the addon domain in the blank field next to
  New Domain Name.
- Step 3: Enter the name of the directory which contains the subdomain
  that the addon domain will point to in the blank field next to
  **Subdomain/FTP Username:** (This directory will be the location for the
  addon domain's files, just as public_html is the location for your
  primary domain's files.)
- Step 4: Type in the password for the new addon domain, and click on
  Add Domain!

**You can upload files directly to this addon domain using the username and password for the addon domain to log in through FTP.**

In order to use a domain name as an addon you need an addon slot. At SiteGround addon domains are allowed on higher plans like Hosting PLUS, Semi Dedicated, etc. If you are using a standard web hosting account you may need to upgrade it from your Customer's area.

Addon domains will need to be registered with a valid domain name registrar before they can be added. Make sure that your account has the ability to use Addon domains before attempting to add one.

Comment: @sparky672 Once you've followed the instructions you may be able to access it via ftp.myaddondomain.net, but it may depend on your hosting.

Comment: I've seen that.  It's on the `Addon` screen as well.  The problem is that `myAddonDomain.net` is already setup, being used for a site, and it has it's own FTP login which gets me to its document root.  I need to be able to grant separate FTP access to just a subdirectory using the same domain name.  I cannot give this person full FTP access to the whole site.  cPanel will not allow creation of an `Addon` domain where one already exists.

Comment: In other words, cPanel allows me to create email accounts using any Addon domain or subdomain.  I'm just wondering if I can create FTP accounts in the same fashion... it's looks like I cannot.

Comment: Could you create a subdomain which points to the sub folder only and provide ftp access that way?

Comment: That would be ideal if it worked.  However, there is no FTP (Addon) associated with subdomains.  I own "x" number of domain names and I am only allowed to have the same "x" number of "Addon" domains.  In other words, cPanel does not allow you to create an "Addon" for a subdomain.  Nor does it give you an FTP account specific to the subdomain.